# AWS Fargate ECS CLI Compose Private Registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to create a Fargate cluster using Cloud Formation in AWS which uses a bunch of images stored in a private registry behind username/password authentication.

This command

```
./ecs-cli.exe compose --project-name AdminUI service up --create-log- 
groups --cluster-config AdminUIConfig
```

results in an error
FATA[0302] Deployment has not completed: Running count has not changed 
for 5.00 minutes

After investigation it appears the problem is because of the lack of basic auth against the repo which holds the images.  How on earth do I pass this?  I am currently running on Windows 10 using VS Code, if that matters.  It feels like it is not client side, it is the cluster itself which needs to be sending the authentication.

Sorry, new to Docker and AWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fargate currently only supports pulling images from an unauthenticated registry (like Docker Hub) or from Amazon ECR.

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definitions):

> The Fargate launch type only supports images in Amazon ECR or public repositories in Docker Hub.